# What does 'EMPTY' mean as a bl_space_type in bpy.types.Panel?

Tags: python, panel

Short version: What does the `bl_space_type` value "EMPTY" mean in the context of `bpy.types.Panel`?

Long version:

I'm doing a deep(ish) dive into the Blender Python API. Currently I'm studying `bpy.types.Panel` in the hopes of improving the panels in my add-ons.  One of the standard fields in Panel classes is [`bl_space_type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html#bpy.types.Panel.bl_space_type). The manual has a list of space types (‘EMPTY’, ‘VIEW_3D’, IMAGE_EDITOR’, ‘NODE_EDITOR’, ‘SEQUENCE_EDITOR’, ‘CLIP_EDITOR’, ‘DOPESHEET_EDITOR’, GRAPH_EDITOR’,
‘NLA_EDITOR’, ‘TEXT_EDITOR’, ‘CONSOLE’, ‘INFO’, ‘TOPBAR’, ‘STATUSBAR’, ‘OUTLINER’, ‘PROPERTIES’, ‘FILE_BROWSER’, ‘SPREADSHEET’, and ‘PREFERENCES’).

Most of the space types correspond to to the various editors and make perfect sense as such and I understand how `bl_space_type` is used in a panel.  I've done the obvious web search for "Blender python bl_space_type EMPTY'; but the search has turned up (sorry for the pun) empty.  None of the proposed "Similar questions" seem to shed any light on the issue.

I am speculating that 'EMPTY', is used as a stand in for "any space type at all"; but I can't find  anything that confirms this.

Does anyone know what the 'EMPTY' `bl_space_type` is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a comment on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249026/42221) I was pointed in the right direction.

Internally, the `'EMPTY'` string is converted into `SPACE_EMPTY`. `SPACE_EMPTY` is used in the C code for various purposes, including as the space type for [file dropboxes](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/editors/space_file/space_file.c#L677) and for newly created empty screens.  It has many other uses related to versioning and detecting uninitialized data; but these are the only two related to the UI.

It is not meant for external use and only included for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

I think it doesn't serve any purpose in the context of panels.

It looks like it is mainly (only) used in the [keymap definitions](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/release/scripts/presets/keyconfig/keymap_data/blender_default.py#L495).

From what I could tell it means it's supposed to be shared by several space types.

For instance every space type can have Window shortcuts, Screen shortcuts, etc.

And Clip, Frame manipulation, Mask editing, Grease Pencil, etc. do not have a particular space type associated with them.

[image]

Comment: [bl_space_type](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html#bpy.types.Panel.bl_space_type} manual entry lists the space types that are used in Panel.  Every one of them _except_ 'EMPTY' is associated with an editor, as described in the manual.   They're used to identify what editors the panel is associated with. It's the usage in the Panel class that I'm asking about..

Comment: Yeah I do understand that, but what I tried to explain is the enum used to define the possible values in the panel class defintion is shared with all the other parts of Blender which need it too. See https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_ui.c#L1481-L1485 and https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_space.c#L100-L193 so the 'EMPTY' enum value is a leftover quirk from python API, it's not supposed to be used by panels (at least imo)

Comment: Yes, I realize that the enum has other values.  That's why I specifically called out the set used by bl_space_type.  'EMPTY' is one of the included ones.  So what is it used for in this context?

Comment: It's not supposed to be used in any capacity for panels, it's written out in the documentation because it's generated automatically from the C code but its single use is for keymap definitions, which share the same enum items. It's like a global function to fetch space type items that's used by several C files, so they're not re-defined in every module. See the call to `rna_enum_space_type_items` here https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_wm_api.c#L1256

Comment: It's exactly the same function that auto-generates the documentation there : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyMap.html?highlight=keymap#bpy.types.KeyMap.space_type

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer for being mostly correct once I understood your comments. It does have one UI use, but that's not expected in the Panel class.

Comment: Alright, thanks for bearing with me, I learnt a thing or two along the way too. Cheers :)